# MVC Bootstrap no icons showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap icons are not shown on my mvc website. I tried to find an issue but failed every time. Below are some configurations which might be helpful in order to find the issue. If anything else is required then please let me know.

**BundleConfig.vb:**

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Module BundleConfig
    ' For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    Public Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"))

        ' Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        ' ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))

        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js"))

        bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/site.css"))
    End Sub
End Module
```

**This is full _Layout.vbhtml code:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".flash").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></span>&nbsp;")
            $(".user").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>&nbsp;")
            $(".file").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span>&nbsp;")
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .jumbotron {
            min-height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            background: url("/Images/Chorus_logo_140.png") center center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", Nothing, New With {.class = "user"})</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services", Nothing, New With {.class = "flash"})</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Program log", "Index", "ProgramLog", Nothing, New With {.class = "file"})</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("EMS Data Quality", "Index", "EmsDataQuality", Nothing, New With {.class = "file"})</li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Documentation<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Changelog", "Index", "ChangeLog", Nothing, New With {.class = "home"})</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Data Flow", "DataFlow", "ChangeLog", Nothing, New With {.class = "home"})</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!--  end navbar -->
            @*<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", New With {.area = ""}, Nothing)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", New With {.area = ""}, Nothing)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>*@
        </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>@DateTime.Now.Year - SABP Development team</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
</body>
</html>
```

**Files Structure:**

[image]

Comment: Try this:   `bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/Content/site.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));`

Comment: @SahilSharma having error by this: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Optimization.IItemTransform'.'

Comment: Bootstrap 4 (which what you're actually using) doesn't include any icons. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/

Comment: @TiesonT.what should i do now to fix?

Comment: Follow the migration docs (http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#components) or switch to using Bootstrap 3. If you used NuGet to add Bootstrap, you need this package instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/3.3.7

Comment: @TiesonT. why bootstrap 4 doesnt contains icons?

Comment: I can't really answer that. You'd have to ask the Bootstrap folks. I assume either a) they didn't want to give preference to a specific icon set, given how ubiquitous Bootstrap has become, or b) they had data (via the custom download, maybe, or perhaps culled from the various CDNs) showing that a fair majority of Bootstrap users weren't actually using the Glyph icons.

Answer (score -1):

The DOM must be loaded to interact with it.
Putting your script in the `<head>` tag will run it before the DOM is loaded.
Adding it just before the `</body>` tag has the benefit of having the DOM available.

But if you insist to add it to the `<head>` tag, then you must amend your script e.g.:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function AddIcon () {
        $(".flash").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></span>&nbsp;")
        $(".user").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>&nbsp;")
        $(".file").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span>&nbsp;")
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddIcon);
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm something is wrong, please check my latest main post update how Layaout code look like and eventually modify it me to check whether work or not. If will work i will mark you as answer.

Answer (score -1):

here you go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function AddIcon() {
            $(".flash").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></span>&nbsp;")
            $(".user").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>&nbsp;")
            $(".file").prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span>&nbsp;")
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddIcon);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .jumbotron {
            min-height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            background: url("/Images/Chorus_logo_140.png") center center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "user" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services", null, new { @class = "flash" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Program log", "Index", "ProgramLog", null, new { @class = "file" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("EMS Data Quality", "Index", "EmsDataQuality", null, new { @class = "file" })</li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Documentation<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Changelog", "Index", "ChangeLog", null, new { @class = "home" })</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Data Flow", "DataFlow", "ChangeLog", null, new { @class = "home" })</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - - SABP Development team</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```